# How to get a broadcast intent on turning data off/on in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to get an intent whenever the user turns off/on mobile data. Not when the the mobile connects with data. For example i can get an intent when the user's connectivity type changes from wifi to mobile data and vice versa or when the user simply connects with internet i can get the intent of whether he connected with wifi or data but my problem is that if im connected with wifi and i turn off/on data i dont get any intent. Is there any way to get in intent just for this ?

Comment: there is no such intent

Comment: VladyslavMatviienko Yes i couldnt find any but im asking is there any way i can myself implement this or get this intent manually or something just to know whenever a user turns off or on his mobile data

Comment: you can't know that while you are on WIFI. When on mobile data, you can receive intents about connection state, but even if the intent says the connection was lost/established, you can't be sure whether user has enabled/disabled it, or the device has lost/found the network. SO basically, you can't know that.